# JQuery Ajax request failing only in mobile browser

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, cakephp

There are numerous posts where people ask this.. but it seems like the majority have issues when they use ajax requests for cross domain connection. I simply use this on the same domain and still cannot manage to get the ajax request to work on my mobile browser... it works perfectly on the desktop browser though.

This is the code I'm using:

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/test/Stores/storeCheck',
    data: $input,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
      alert("success");
    },
    error:function (xhr) {
      alert("failed");
    }
});
```

**PHP controller (cakephp)**

```
function storeCheck () {

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

        //Selecting values from the DB and returning them in $result

        $this->autoRender = false;
        return (json_encode($result));

    }

}
```

In my mobile browser the ajax request is made, and it just goes on until it reaches the error event showing me the failed alert popup. I've tried using JSONP as some suggested, but with no success. Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Br,
A

Comment: Can you change the failed alert a bit to debug? `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(jqXHR);console.log(textStatus);console.log(errorThrown)};` and update the question with the response?

Comment: Don't know if it'll help your problem, but in the past I've had issues with Debug being on during ajax requests.

Comment: Nunser/Joshua, I got a "parserror, Unable to parse JSON string" when i debugged in the mobile browser. Does that make sense? Am I doing something wrong?

Thx for helping out.

Comment: Yes, that error means that the response your getting does not come in json format... Try this, change the `return (json_encode($result));` to `echo json_encode($result);` and post the error (if any) you get with the debug code I commented first please.

Comment: The error I got when changed to echo json_encode($result); was "Unexpected token <". I believe this is because of me not defining a layout in cakephp (because I dont want a layout attached to this request). When I do an echo the result seems therefore to be embedded in a HTML page (like so <html>...) The "<" I believe cannot be recognized. Am I right?

Comment: Success! A combination of Nunsers echo change and Joshuas Debug removal made it work. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue. I used echo instead of return in my controller function. I also turned of the Debug for my ajax request in the controller:

```
function storeCheck () {

if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

    Configure::write('debug', 0);

    //Selecting values from the DB and returning them in $result

    $this->autoRender = false;
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

}

Comment: Glad to see it working, but do try to debug the "Unexpected token <" issue. If you do `echo json_encode($result);return;`, does it gives the same error? If it does give the same error, then maybe the result has a `<` character around somewhere. It *is not* a layout problem, `$this->autoRender = false` prevents that (doesn't attach layout *or* view, so the echo should be clean of extra markup). debug > 0 is to help you resolve problems, if you bypass it like that the warning just doesn't show, but it may still be a problem, it's good practice to try and solve it :)

Comment: You definitely have a point there. I'll take a look at it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: When I debugged and took a closer look at the object returned in the ajax request (just before Unable to parse JSON string) I see a responseText in it showing the data returned from the db in JSON format. BUT, it is also some data appended to it at the end like so:

"[{"stores":{"name":"test","address":"test 43, Stockholm, Sweden"}}]<h2>View file &quo…"

I bet the "<h2>..." is the part it doesn't like?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't like that, and also the error, even though you didn't copy all of it, is probably a "view not found error". Maybe post a different question with that error if you can't solve it by yourself, because these comments are deviating from the original question :)

Comment: But it shouldn't look for a view when autorender is set to false.. am I right?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't. Put a `return;` after the echo an see if that fixes it